# question about the application of linear algebra to differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra

In the Gilbert Strang's textbook Introduction to Linear Algebra,
the chapter about application to differential equation, it first mentions the solution of $\frac{\mathrm d  u}{\mathrm d t}=\lambda u$  is $u(t)=Ce^{\lambda t}$.
Then it mentions that if there are $n$ equations contain square matrix, the $n$ "pure expotential solution" $u=Xe^{\lambda t}$.
My question is why $X$ appears in the solution when there are $n$ equations?

Many thanks in advanced.
[the original text content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW0kv.png)

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a $n \times n$ - matrix, we consider the linear system

$$(*) \quad u'=Au.$$

Now let $ \lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ a corresponding eigenvector, hence $Ax= \lambda x$ and $x \ne 0$, then put

$$u(t)= e^{ \lambda t}x.$$

Then we have $Au(t)= e^{ \lambda t}Ax= \lambda e^{ \lambda t}x=u'(t).$ Thus, $u$ is a solution of $(*)$.